# Large data set for testing kernel logistic regression

Tags: logistic, dataset, large-data, kernel-trick

Does anyone know of a large data set (upwards of $10^7$ rows, but I'll take $10^5$ as well) that would be appropriate for testing kernel logistic regression?  Continuous variables, 2 to 50 independent variables?  Would prefer business-like data as opposed to scientific (weather, chemical, bio ...).

Comment: What is your objective?  To validate an implementation?  Just to play around and familiarize yourself with the methodology? Or...

Comment: Mainly to validate an implementation and benchmark.

Comment: In that case, you could always construct an artificial dataset, e.g., in R, and dump it out into a file with the appropriate structure.  The advantage that has over a "natural" dataset is that you know the true model, so validation of the code is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at some of the data sets on the [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) textbook website.  They might be on the small side (most have between $10^2$ to $10^5$ observations, but it's a faily varied selection of datasets.

Specifically, you might want to look at:

- [Marketing](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/datasets/marketing.info) (may be a good business dataset)

  > A total of N=9409 questionnaires containg 502 questions were 
  >   filled out by shopping mall customers in the San Francisco Bay area.
  >
  > The dataset income.data is an extract from this survey. It consists of 
  >   14 demographic attributes. The dataset is a good mixture of categorical 
  >   and continuos variables with a lot of missing data. This is characteristic 
  >   for data mining applications.
  >
  > The goal is to predict the Anual Income of Household from the other 13
  >   demographics  attributes.
- Zip Code OCR (sorry, can't post more than two hyperlinks)

  > Normalized handwritten digits, automatically
  >   scanned from envelopes by the U.S. Postal Service. The original
  >   scanned digits are binary and of different sizes and orientations; the
  >   images  here have been deslanted and size normalized, resulting
  >   in 16 x 16 grayscale images (Le Cun et al., 1990).
  >
  > The data are in two gzipped files, and each line consists of the digit
  >   id (0-9) followed by the 256 grayscale values.
  >
  > There are 7291 training observations and 2007 test observations,
  >   distributed as follows:
  >
  > ```
  >          0    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 Total
  > Train 1194 1005 731 658 652 556 664 645 542 644 7291
  > Test   359  264 198 166 200 160 170 147 166 177 2007
  > ```